# Is there a function like __eq__, but with 3 or more objects?

Tags: python, class, methods

is there a magic method like __eq__ to compare more than 2 objects?

I tried to put more than two arguments, but there is an error

Comment: No.  Try something like `all(a == x for x in (b, c, d, ...))`, comparing all of the objects to the first object.

Comment: As this smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can write `a == b == c`, which has the same meaning as `a == b and b == c`. Since equality is transitive, you can infer that if `a == b` is true and `b == c` is true, then `a == c` is true as well. (Transitivity is something you need to keep in mind if defining `__eq__` for one of your own classes.)

Comment: This chaining extends to any number of comparisons: `a == b == c == d`, `a == b == c == d == e`, etc. Whenever such a chain is true, you can infer that any two values in the chain are equal to each other. (But for longer chains, using `all` is simpler.)